# ajax return data is failing

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am using javascript to fetch values for a select option - triggered by a change in previous select option.

```
        $('#groupid, #lbl_groupid').hide();
        $('#subgroupid, #lbl_subgroupid').hide();

        $('#managerid').change(function(){
            var manager_id = $('#managerid').val();                
            if (manager_id != "")
            {
            var post_url = "nab1/index.php/main_page/get_groups/" + manager_id;

            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: post_url,
              success: function(group_list) //we're calling the response json array 'cities'
              {
                $('#groupid').empty();
                $('#groupid, #lbl_groupid').show();

                $.each(data,function(id,value) 
                {

                  var opt = $('<option />'); // here we're creating a new select option for each group
                      opt.val(id);
                      opt.text(value);
                      $('#groupid').append(opt); 
            });
           } //end success
     }); //end AJAX
} else {
    $('#groupid').empty();
    $('#groupid, #lbl_groupid').hide();
}//end if
}); //end change
```

When i am calling function in the browser `get_groups` along with a parameter i am getting `{"4":"nab_group_1_1","6":"nab_group_2_1"}`

however options are not being populated.

I have following code in controller

```
function get_groups()
{
    $manager = $this->uri->segment(3);

    $group_list = $this->models_personnel->get_groups_by_managerid($manager);
    //header('Content-Type: application/x-json; charset=utf-8');    
    echo  json_encode($group_list);

}
```

can somebody please tell whats wrong.

When i am using return from ajax call in an alert its showing me code of the current page.
Please tell me how can i effectively implement this so that select option are properly populated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: just set data type to ajax call as dataType:'json',

Comment: Make sure your URL hit properly `nab1/index.php/main_page/get_groups/` it seems you are using codeigniter check your ajax request with the help of firebug or developers tool

Comment: @sohil I have set dataType  still no response.
 $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: post_url,
                  dataType: "json",
                  success: function(group_list)

Comment: @jogesh_pi3 Yes I am using codeigniter and checked in firebug request is executed but Post is blank and response is html souce code of the page.

Comment: I think i should be getting json object in response.
Why i am getting source code for response.
Besides how can i know if at all i am getting any response .
Success seems to be working as second option  is being displayed

Comment: You are probably using wrong variable `data`. Try `$.each(group_list,function(id,value)`

Comment: your loop $.each(data,function(id,value) {}) is also wrong you are getting response in variable group_list and you are not using it. first check your response by using console.log(group_list) in success then loop it by this $.each(group_list,function(id,value) {})

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake in the code here:

```
$.each(data,function(id,value)
```

That should be:

```
$.each(group_list,function(id,value)
```

Because you named the returned data `group_list` in here:

```
success: function(group_list)
```

Also, add `dataType: "json",` to your ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: post_url,
    dataType: "json",
    // etc
```